# How to Migrate product from magento 1.9.3.0 to 2.1.7?

Tags: magento, migration

I want to migrate product, category from magento 1.9.3.0 to 2.1.7. How to do it? I used UberTheme Migration tool. But it could not work. Show

CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '539' for key 'PRIMARY'. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` (`attribute_id`, `media_type`, `disabled`, `value_id`, `value`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4)

in setp5 then stop the script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use UberTheme Migration Tool. It's not working properly. Instead of that you can use Magento's default migration tool. Which can not even products but it will import orders, attributes, attributes set etc. Almost all the data from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

I had personally used it and it's really work fine. Below is the URL it may help you.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html